# Making a specific table in overleaf (assessment criteria)

Tags: tables

I am a total newbie to coding and latex, & have no clue what I am doing. I am trying to make the table on the left in overleaf, however, I am not succeeding. I have no clue how I will make ex the first row where it sais "Quality assessment criteria" only have one coloumn, how to make "Level" cover all coloumns except the 1st, or the second row where it sais "Element", cover two rows. My text in the table also gets these weird big spaces between the words, and I only want to have single space between my letters. If someone either have an idea of a completely new table template to use, or would like to help me make my initial code better:

```
\documentclass
\begin{center}
\begin{tabular}{ | m{2.5em} | m{2.5cm}| m{2.5cm} | m{2.5cm} | m{2.5cm}| m{2.58cm} | } % 15.5
  \hline
   \textbf{Quality assessment criteria} \\
   \hline
  \textbf{Element }& \textbf{Level} & \textbf{-} & \textbf{- }& \textbf{-} & \textbf{-} \\ 
  \hline
 - & 0-Absence & 1 - Low & 2 - Medium & 3 - High & Not applicable \\
    \hline
 1. Theory robustness  & The article does not provide enough information to assess this criterion & Poor awareness of existing literature and debates.
Under or over referenced
Low validity of theory & Basic understanding of the issues around the topic being discussed. The theory weakly is related to data & Deep and broad knowledge of relevant literature and theory relevant for addressing the research. 
Good relation theory-data & This element is not applicable to the document or study  \\
    \hline
 - & - & - & - & - & This element is not applicable to the document or study  \\
    \hline 
 - & - & - & - & - & This element is not applicable to the document or study  \\
    \hline 
 - & - & - & - & - & This element is not applicable to the document or study \\
    \hline 
 - & - & - & - & - & This element is not applicable to the document or study  \\
    \hline 
 - & - & - & - & - & This element is not applicable to the document or study  \\
    \hline 
 - & - & - & - & - & This element is not applicable to the document or study \\
    \hline 
 - & - & - & - & - & This element is not applicable to the document or study \\
    \hline 
 - & - & - & - & - & This element is not applicable to the document or study \\
    \hline 
\end{tabular}
\end{center}
\end{document}
```

[image: What I want to make VS my poor try]

[image]

Comment: I think LaTeX by default justifies cell text. You need to set the alignment to raggedright.

Comment: Regarding cells that span multiple rows or columns, you may want to take a look at the `\multirow` and the `\multicolumn` commands.

Comment: Which documentclass you use? How is defined your document pages layout?

Comment: You still not inform us, which document class you use, what is size of `\textwidth`. For such hude table this are very important data.

Answer (score 3):

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[margin=1cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{tabularray}
\begin{document}
\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}
\begin{tblr}
{
colspec={X[l,m]X[l,m]X[l,m]X[l,m]X[l,m]X[l,m]},
cell{1}{1}={c=6}{halign=c},
cell{2}{1}={r=2}{halign=c},
cell{2}{2}={c=5}{halign=c},
row{1-3}={font=\bfseries},
row{4-Z}={valign=h},
hlines,vlines
}
Quality assessment criteria &           &         &            &          &                                                         \\
Element                     & Level     &         &            &          &                                                         \\
                            & 0-Absence & 1 - Low & 2 - Medium & 3 - High & Not applicable                                          \\
1. Theory robustness  & The article does not provide enough information to assess this criterion & Poor awareness of existing literature and debates. Under or over referenced Low validity of theory & Basic understanding of the issues around the topic being discussed. The theory weakly is related to data & Deep and broad knowledge of relevant literature and theory relevant for addressing the research. Good relation theory-data & This element is not applicable to the document or study  \\
-                           & -         & -       & -          & -        & This element is not applicable to the document or study \\
-                           & -         & -       & -          & -        & This element is not applicable to the document or study \\
-                           & -         & -       & -          & -        & This element is not applicable to the document or study \\
-                           & -         & -       & -          & -        & This element is not applicable to the document or study \\
-                           & -         & -       & -          & -        & This element is not applicable to the document or study \\
-                           & -         & -       & -          & -        & This element is not applicable to the document or study \\
-                           & -         & -       & -          & -        & This element is not applicable to the document or study \\
-                           & -         & -       & -          & -        & This element is not applicable to the document or study \\
\end{tblr}
\end{document}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thankyou so so much Clara! I really appreciate it.
I was wondering if you have any ideas on how I can make the whole table fit in one page (it will be one page on the appendix), as it does in the example i provided? It is also not wide enough to make the text fit inside each box.

Comment: @MiriamLinneaRølland For this multi-column table, you should give your textwidth. If it is the picture you just added, you can consider reducing the font size.

Answer (score 2):

- You apparently are not willing to help us to help you. I kindly ask you for missing information, but not provide them so far )so I downvote your question)
- Since we are left to guessing, The following suggestion can serve only for starting point.
- For better spacing text in table's cells I would rotate table by use `rotating` package and for text in it use `\small` font size:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{geometry}

\usepackage{ragged2e}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{rotating}

\begin{document}
    \begin{sidewaystable}
    \small
    \setlength{\tabcolsep}{3pt}
\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{ | *{6}{>{\RaggedRight\hspace{0pt}}X|} } % 15.5
    \hline
\multicolumn{6}{|l|}{\textbf{Quality assessment criteria}}                        \\
    \hline
    &   \multicolumn{5}{c|}{\textbf{Level}}                                      \\
    \cline{2-6}
\textbf{Element}
    &  \textbf{0 - Absence} 
        & \textbf{1 - Low} 
            & \textbf{2 - Medium} 
                &  \textbf{3 - High} 
                    &  \textbf{Not applicable}                                  \\
    \hline
1. Theory robustness  
    & The article does not provide enough information to assess this criterion.
        & Poor awareness of existing literature and debates. Under or over referenced. Low validity of theory. 
            & Basic understanding of the issues around the topic being discussed. The theory weakly is related to data. 
                & Deep and broad knowledge of relevant literature and theory relevant for addressing the research. Good relation theory-data 
                    & This element is not applicable to the document or study.  \\
    \hline
2. Implication for practice
    & The article does not provide enough information to assess this criterion. 
        & - & - & - & This element is not applicable to the document or study    \\
    \hline
3. Methodology. Data supporting 
    & The article does not provide enough information to assess this criterion. 
        & - & - & - & This element is not applicable to the document or study    \\
    \hline
4. Generalisibility
    & The article does not provide enough information to assess this criterion.
        & - & - & - & This element is not applicable to the document or study    \\
    \hline
4. Contribution

Plus a short statement summarizing the article's contribution
    & The article does not provide enough information to assess this criterion.
        & - & - & - & This element is not applicable to the document or study    \\
    \hline
\end{tabularx}
\end{sidewaystable}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Nicer result yan be obtain by use `tabullaray` package (similarly as do @Clara in her answer, +1):

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{geometry}

\usepackage{ragged2e}
\usepackage{tabularray}
\usepackage{rotating}

\begin{document}
    \begin{sidewaystable}
    \small
    \setlength{\tabcolsep}{3pt}
\begin{tblr}{hlines, vlines,
             colspec = {*{6}{X[appto=\RaggedRight]} },
             colsep  = {3pt},
             row{1-3} = {font=\bfseries}
            }
\SetCell[c=6]{l}    Quality assessment criteria                                  \\
\SetCell[r=2]{l}   Element
    & \SetCell[c=5]{l}    Level                                                  \\
    &   0 - Absence  
        &   1 - Low 
            &   2 - Medium 
                &   3 - High 
                    &   Not applicable                                          \\
1. Theory robustness  
    & The article does not provide enough information to assess this criterion.
        & Poor awareness of existing literature and debates. Under or over referenced. Low validity of theory. 
            & Basic understanding of the issues around the topic being discussed. The theory weakly is related to data. 
                & Deep and broad knowledge of relevant literature and theory relevant for addressing the research. Good relation theory-data 
                    & This element is not applicable to the document or study.  \\
2. Implication for practice
    & The article does not provide enough information to assess this criterion. 
        & - & - & - & This element is not applicable to the document or study    \\
3. Methodology. Data supporting 
    & The article does not provide enough information to assess this criterion. 
        & - & - & - & This element is not applicable to the document or study    \\
4. Generalisibility
    & The article does not provide enough information to assess this criterion.
        & - & - & - & This element is not applicable to the document or study    \\
4. Contribution

Plus a short statement summarizing the article's contribution
    & The article does not provide enough information to assess this criterion.
        & Only to the population studied
            & Generalisable to organisations of similar characteristic
                & High level of generalisabilty
                    & This element is not applicable to the document or study    \\
\end{tblr}
    \end{sidewaystable}
\end{document}
```

[image]